# Windows Boot Configuration Data (BCD) viewer for linux

Tags: dual-boot, windows, boot-loader

Is there such a thing as a Windows Boot Configuration Data (BCD) viewer for Linux?

I understand that BCD files are 'like registry hives' and tools exist to read registry hives for Linux.

Is there a way to see the contents, the list of partitions etc, that a BCD file contains? It used to be easy with `boot.ini` files but not anymore!

My use case is this: I have a hidden partition that is not accessible from Windows (it's a system partition) and I want to read the BCD file it has. On the same system, both that partition and the Windows boot partition have boot managers and BCD files and I'm trying to sort this out (and dual-boot Linux eventually).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Running `apt-cache search windows registry` on Debian to look for packages that may suit your purpose brings up five candidates. You can make a [similar search on `packages.debian.org`](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+registry+site%3Apackages.debian.org), or search [on the Debian packages site](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) (use the “search package directories” form, and make sure to select “descriptions”).

[Chntpw](http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/) was developed to change a forgotten Windows administrator password, but it can view and edit any registry entry. There's a boot CD on the site.

Hivex is a library for accessing Windows registry hives. It's part of [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/), a suite of tools to work with virtual machine images from the host. It comes with [command line tools to extract and edit registry entries](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/libhivex-windows-registry-hive-extractor-library/). It [supports BCD hives](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/use-hivex-to-unpack-a-windows-boot-configuration-data-bcd-hive/).

[Parse::Win32Registry](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-Win32Registry/) is a Perl module for reading Windows registry files.

[RegLookup](http://projects.sentinelchicken.org/reglookup/) is a small utility to read Windows registry hives.

[Samba](http://www.samba.org/) comes with tools to access the Windows registry: `editreg` in Samba 3, and `regshell` and more in Samba 4. In Debian (only unstable right now), they're in the [`registry-tools`](http://packages.debian.org/sid/registry-tools) package.

Answer (score 6):

I've started writing a Python library for manipulating the Windows BCD. The repository is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/wodny/libbcd0).

Comment: Your link give a HTTP 404 error, have you move your libbcd repository somewhere else ? If so, can you update the link in your answer ?

Comment: I've done a reupload on GitHub. Note it's an old library. I used it once in production because I had no other choice but I wouldn't call it production-ready.

Comment: Very interesting... Can you precise the python version your program requires in your github project ? BTW : `pip search hivex` returned nothing, where did you find this module that you import in [BCD.py#L19](https://github.com/wodny/libbcd0/blob/master/BCD.py#L19) ?

Comment: I've added "2" to the project's description because I have no idea what it really currently requires. It was probably Python 2.6 at the time of writing (Debian Squeeze). Hivex probably came from the Debian repo (https://packages.debian.org/buster/python-hivex).

Comment: Thanks. I think you can add this link to your [README.txt](https://github.com/wodny/libbcd0/blob/master/README.txt) : https://github.com/libguestfs/hivex so that people will know where its coming from :))

Comment: I don't think anyone would benefit from it. I don't want to pretend that the library is maintained or that I'm sure where the hivex binding came from. There is also no guarantee the API didn't change in 9 years. The first result from Google gives an URL. If someone is brave enough to try to use an 9-year old experiment will certainly manage to find a hivex binding.

Comment: Don't understimate your work :) Just because it's old doesn't mean nobody would benefit from it. Someone with the competence could very well fork your project and continue it. BTW : I couldn't find any python module that is able to decode a Boot Configuration Data file from Linux.

Comment: I didn't mean nobody could benefit from the project as a whole. I meant that nobody would benefit from adding URL to hivex (answering your previous suggestion) and I've stated why. Further, I wrote exactly about the competence. If someone is competent enough to touch system-level stuff the repo at its current state will be enough and everything I can provide. The project has been forked (https://github.com/trolldbois/bcdedit).

Comment: OK, got it. Cheers.