# GRUB loads always windows in safe mode

Tags: fedora, boot, windows, dual-boot, grub

I've installed Fedora 31 on a notebook with Windows 10, GRUB shows me different options on boot, and when I choose Windows the system starts but always in safe mode. I have no options to load Windows 10 normally.

This is the boot sequence given by GRUB Customizer:

```
insmod part_gpt
insmod fat
set root='hd0,gpt1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  B0DE-B937
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root B0DE-B937
fi
chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
```

And this is the result of `fdisk -l` command:

```
Device           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1         2048    1026047    1024000   500M EFI System
/dev/sda2      1026048    1107967      81920    40M unknown
/dev/sda3      1107968    1370111     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4      1370112    2906111    1536000   750M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5      2906112 1406771199 1403865088 669,4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6   1933588480 1937344511    3756032   1,8G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7   1937344512 1953523119   16178608   7,7G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda8   1406771200 1408868351    2097152     1G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9   1408868352 1933588479  524720128 250,2G Linux LVM
```

Can anyone help me setting up GRUB to load Windows correctly? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your GRUB configuration is starting the Windows boot manager `bootmgfw.efi` correctly. The problem must be in the configuration of `bootmgfw.efi` itself. On UEFI-based systems, it is located in `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/BCD` on the EFI System Partition (your `sda1`) and unfortunately it is in binary format (essentially the same format as Windows Registry files).

In Windows, starting a command prompt as an Administrator and using the command `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot` might help; but any further discussion on fixing the Windows 10 bootloader would be more on-topic [in Super User.SE](https://superuser.com).

[This question lists some tools you might be able to use for editing the BCD file in Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17433/258991), although the process is... quite technical.

See also this webpage: https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/04/03/use-hivex-to-unpack-a-windows-boot-configuration-data-bcd-hive/